# Some how I broke butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

Some how I managed to break something in my eclipse setup that is breaking butterknife for any **new** views I try to inject.  The "old" views still seem to be fine.

This one works:

```
    @InjectView(R.id.sign_out_button)
    Button signOutButton;
```

this one does not

```
    @InjectView(R.id.map_button) 
    Button mapButton;
```

When I add the new field I get this in the generated java file under .apt_generated

```
   view = finder.findRequiredView(source, 0, "field 'mapButton'");
```

vs this for the "old" field

```
   view = finder.findRequiredView(source, 2131165280, "field 'signOutButton' and method
```

note the 0 vs 2131165280

**The error message I get is map_button cannot be resolved or is not a field**

And indeed if I look under gen/my_package/R.java there is no entry for map_button, but there is one for sign_out_button.

I have tried cleaning the project and restarting the ide many times.  Anyone have any ideas as to what might be wrong?

---

#### Solved

Turns out this was a really dumb mistake.  I had not added the button to the xml file.  Butterknife helps with the code injection but you still need to add the button to the layout file.

Comment: Have you checked that there's no problems in any of your XML files? If there's an error the R file won't be generated properly, which could be why the sign_out_button isn't being detected

Comment: I don't see any issue with any of the xml files, and if I try to add a button via xml, it does get added to R.id

Comment: OK really dumb mistake.  I helps if you add the button to in the fragment xml file.

Comment: Yes that would help :) glad you got it fixed